# Modify data in a pointer across fork()?

Tags: c++, pointers, fork

Let's say I have a class declared...

```
class foo {
  public:
    int i;
    foo(int j) { i = j; }
};
```

Then, I use it in code like this:

```
foo *bar = new foo(17);

cout << "Bar is " << bar->i << endl;

if (!fork()) {
  bar->i = 2;
  exit(0);
}

cout << "Bar is now " << bar->i << endl;
```

I compile this with `g++` and run the executable. And I get the following output:

```
me@computer:~$ ./a.out
Bar is 17
Bar is now 17
```

I have a similar problem, where I need a pointer to a class (slightly more complex than the example) modified within an `if (!fork())` block. Is there any way to do this?

I am able to convert this class to and from a string, if that makes it easier. I am using C++11 and `cmake`, should that be relevant.

Update: Threads are working wonders for me right now. Thanks you, everybody. Here's what I did, essentially:

```
void blob(foo *bar)
{
  bar->i = 2;
}

int main()
{
  foo *bar = new foo(17);
  thread th (blob,bar);
  th.detach();
  delete bar;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will not get a useful answer unless you explain to us exactly what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: I am writing a server that needs to handle multiple clients at once.

Comment: That's not very helpful. Do you need shared state? Is the server I/O intensive? CPU intensive? How many clients? Are you familiar with C++ libraries like boost? We need lots more information than just something that vague as there are tons of ways to handle multiple clients.

Comment: Also, if the code you wrote above worked any differently, `fork` would be totally unusable. Imagine if each process received a different block of data and, to parse it, did `foo *bar = new foo (data_received)`. If those two operations interacted in any way, the data from each client couldn't be correctly processed. Sharing has to be *very* carefully managed!

Comment: Your new code is quite pointless. You create a thread and then wait for it to finish. What's the point of that? You haven't arranged any data sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as soon as you do fork, you go spawn a completely different process with a completely separate (but initially duplicated) memory. Whatever you modify there is not going to be reflected in the main process or vice versa (after the fork).

You need to use **threads** for this.

Comment: The whole reason why I need this is because I'm writing for a server that needs to handle multiple clients at once. Will threads work for that?

Comment: @JohnNunley There are many different ways to write servers that need to handle multiple clients. Thread per connection, thread pool, process per connection, select loop, and many more. Why not ask the best way to do whatever it is you're actually trying to do and give as much information about what you're trying to do as you can.

Comment: if you insist on forks, then you have to look into possible inter-process communication techniques,  like shared memory, mailboxes, fifos, sockets, ...

Answer (score 0):

Once you fork, the new child process has an independent address space.  Any changes in the parent are invisible to the child and any changes in the child are invisible to the parent.  Now behind the scenes, most fork implementations use copy-on-write so that it only duplicates a page of physical RAM once either the parent or child starts writing to it, but this is all hidden from the user processes.

You'll need to either use threads or some sort of [interprocess communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).  There are many ways to do this, all with their own tradeoffs.